# My Angular Program can't refetch data from the same url

Tags: angular

I have a function that will fetch data from the server with `get` method, it works fine, then I update the data with `post` method. After that, I want to automatically refresh the data by using the first method. But it returns the old data. Here'is my code:

```
getDataPerusahaan() {
  this.dp.getData('kustomer/perusahaan').subscribe(data=>{
    console.log(data)
  })}
```

For editing the data I do:

```
async ubahPerusahaan(){
let loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
  message:"Loading . . ."
})
loading.present()
let body = new FormData();
body.append('namaPerusahaan', this.namaPerusahaan)
body.append('alamatPerusahaan', this.alamatPerusahaan)
if(this.gambar){
  body.append("imageFile", this.gambar)
}
this.dp.uploadData(body, "perusahaan/edit").subscribe(async (data)=>{
  loading.dismiss()
  if(await data["affectedRows"] == 1){  
    this.getDataPerusahaan()
  } else{
    this.alertService.error("Ada kesalahan silahkan coba lagi");
  } 
})
```

}

Here is the code for `dp.getData`:

```
postData(body, file){
    let type="application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    let headers= new HttpHeaders({
        "Authorization":"Bearer "+localStorage.getItem("token")
    });
    return this.http.post(this.server+file, body, {headers:headers})
    .pipe(
        catchError(error=>{
            if(error.status==403){
                this.router.navigateByUrl('userlogin')
            }else if(error.status==500){
                return {gagal:true, message:error.message}
            }
            return error
        }),
        map(data => {
            return data
        }),
    );
}
getData(file){
    let type="application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    let headers= new HttpHeaders({
        "Authorization":"Bearer "+localStorage.getItem("token")
    });
    return this.http.get(this.server+file, {headers:headers})
    .pipe(
        catchError(error=>{
            if(error.status==403){
                this.router.navigateByUrl('userlogin')
            }else if(error.status==500){
                return {gagal:true, message:error.message}
            }
            return error
        }),
        map(data => {
            return data
        }),
      );
}
```

Comment: You know those CORS headers are completely useless right..?

Comment: No problem (and not actually angular related). CORS headers need to be set by the server, not the browser..

Comment: ok thanks for the information

Comment: Inspecting your network tab in the browser, does your second GET kustomer/perusahaan return the updated data?

Comment: if I do it immediately after I update it, it returns the old data. but if I wait a minute, it gets the new data